# Unable to access custom attribute value in an ASP MVC Core Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ColumnAttribute : Attribute
{

    public ColumnAttribute(int size)
    {
        Class = "col-md-" + size.ToString();
    }

    public string Class { get; set; }
}
```

And a generic Editor Template that loops through all the properties in the model and spits out the required markup:

```
@model dynamic

@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if (prop.TemplateHint == "HiddenInput")
    {
        @Html.Hidden(prop.PropertyName)
    }
    else
    {

      //Access properties attribute and use it to populate class

       <div class="">

       @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)

      </div>
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access the custom ColumnAttribute on properties that have it so that I can add the given class to the editors wrapping div.

I have tried :

```
var Member = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.GetMember(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName);
var attr = Member[0].GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>();
```

But had no success as "ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType" is null.

Anyone got any ideas? (Many thanks in advance)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to apply this to `ViewData`.  Have you tried it against the actual view `Model`?

Comment: Sorry @Brad not quite sure what that looks like. Could you provide a code example?

Comment: In your Razor views something like  `@Model.GetType().GetProperties().GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Brad. Worked it out :

```
@model dynamic

@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if (prop.TemplateHint == "HiddenInput")
    {
        @Html.Hidden(prop.PropertyName)
    }
    else
    {

             string attrclass = "";

             Type type = prop.ContainerType;

             if (type != null)
             {

                var attr = type.GetMember(prop.PropertyName)[0].GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>();

                if(attr!= null)
                {
                    attrclass = attr.Class;
                }


              }

            <div class="@attrclass">
                <div class="input-field">

                    @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)

                </div>

            </div>

}
```